# Clients connecting to wrong dfs share

Tags: windows-server-2008, dfs, network-share

I am having a lot of trouble with my clients connecting to the wrong dfs share, how do I ensure that clients only connect to the nearest dfs share.

I have two file shares connected by a vpn connection and when the clients connect to the wrong share it really slows down logon and clogs up the internet connection so I really need to connect to the file share which is in the same office as the client machine.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you assign the IP ranges to multiple sites in active directory? DFS uses the site configuration information out of the site management in active directory.

Comment: Link to read: [Technet site documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc782048(v=ws.10).aspx). Dfs is "site-aware" - if your sites are configured correctly, Dfs connections will prefer replicas in the same site as the client.